# Is there an official documenation for REG file recommended encoding?

Tags: windows, registry, file-format, byte-order-mark, regedit

When exporting a REG file via Windows' built-in tools (UI `regedit.exe` or command line `reg import`), it uses **UTF16 LE** with **BOM**.

[The Wikipedia .reg entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.reg) claims on Windows 2000 and later, REG files are Unicode-based, while on Windows 9x and NT 4.0 systems, they are are ANSI-based, but the Wikipedia's entry's original reference [makes no such claim](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg-file-9c7f37cf-a5e9-e1cd-c4fa-2a26218a1a23)!

So is there any official Microsoft source that does mention it, and specifically UTF16 LE + BOM? The interesting part is that source is supposed to mention it's only a recommendation anyway, since REG files can safely use UTF8 or just ANSI as long as the registry contents don't use relevant characters.